# symfony 5.3 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate run version that already executed

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I updated my symfony project to version 5.3.
changed file doctrine_migrations.yaml
from:

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
  dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    namespace: DoctrineMigrations
```

to:

```yaml
doctrine_migrations:
  migrations_paths:
    DoctrineMigrations: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
```

and now when I run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

the first version that already exceuted' try to run' and get error:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'regions' already exists

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove previous migrations and generate a new one with

`php bin/console make:migration`

If your database is up to date, the new migration should be empty.

You could also empty the databse table "Migrations" to have a fresh start.

(Commit and backup files in case you want to revert)

Comment: thanks, but I dont want to remove previous migrations.